# trigger to autofill the child field date with the parent field date

Tags: trigger

I wrote a trigger so that when i enter a date in parent field it should automatically reflect in child field.
here is a code i wrote but somehow the date is not reflected in the child field.

```
trigger PaymentdateTrigger on Invoice__c (after update, after insert) {

map<Id,Date> updatemap = new map<Id,Date>();

for(Invoice__c a: trigger.new)
{
 updatemap.put(a.Id,a.Paymentdate__c);
}

if (updatemap.size() > 0)
    {
        Accountancy__c[] paymentdate = [Select Id,Paymentdate__c from Accountancy__c where Invoice__c IN : updatemap.Keyset()];

    for(Accountancy__c pd:paymentdate)
        {
            pd.Paymentdate__c = updatemap.get(pd.Invoice__c);
        }
       update paymentdate;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: What does "It's not working" mean? Are you receiving an error? What specific behavior do you get? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: the date i enter in the parent field is not reflected in the child field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include Invoice__c in your SELECT statement

Although I wasn't able to find the SF documentation, records in trigger context variables (Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap) are probably the only instance where all non-null fields are available: https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/which-fields-are-accessible-in-a-trigger-new-record-without-performing-a-soql-query-in-salesforce/.

SOQL & SOSL record fields are only available if they're included in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is working fine now.

Comment: It would have been a great answer if you could explain your solution more constructively.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. Thanks, I was on my way to including a better explanation, but couldn't find a good SF documentation link fast enough.